# Problems with getRoutingService().calculateRoute parameters

Tags: here-maps-rest, heremaps

I am looking into the HereMaps as a possible map provider for our company and am having difficulty with the return `params` for `calculateRoute`. I am trying to get the route instructions to be returned from the endpoint but it fails when trying to do so. I am currently passing in ...

```
var routingParameters = {
    routingMode: 'fast',
    transportMode: 'truck',
    // The start point of the route:
    origin: position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude,
    // The end point of the route:
    destination: '50.672770,-120.375370',
    return: 'polyline',
};
```

This seems to work however when i try to do `return: 'polyline, actions, instructions',` to get the instruction info the route request fails. I noticed in the docs that these are available but don't seem to work for my case. My guess is it may be due to being on the free version for now. Any help is appreciated.